# Table Relationship Reference Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a web application where a contractor (electrician, roofer, plumber) etc can make a proposal online. Pictures, youtube videos of the project, and a text description will be provided to the contractor from the customer.

So far I am working on the pictures feature using carrierwave

This is the table of this model in my schema

```
  create_table "project_pictures", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Here are my two records in my rails console

```
 ProjectPicture Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "project_pictures".* FROM "project_pictures"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ProjectPicture id: 2, name: "Request for Siding Quote Customer A", picture: "siding.jpg", created_at: "2013-08-15 16:10:22", updated_at: "2013-08-15 16:47:02">, #<ProjectPicture id: 1, name: "Request for Siding Quote Customer A", picture: "sidingrequest.jpg", created_at: "2013-08-14 01:54:27", updated_at: "2013-08-15 16:47:39">]>
```

The thing is I am trying to link multiple pictures to one customer. Lets say the above two pictures belong to one customer and there are two rows because there are two pictures.

How do I reference that in the table, lets say I have one customer and thats me "judy"
both the record should reference judy's id?

and then eventually in the view, I can draw both pictures out using an image tag that belong to the customer id 1 - with name = "judy" or just customer id = 1?

If I am not making things clear please let me know, I am not that familiar with tables relationships and which relationship will help me the most.

Answer (score 0):

`create table :projects do |t|
    t.references :clients
    t.timestamps
  end`

create_table :pictures do |t|
    t.string :name, null:false
    t.string :location, null:false
    t.references :projects, null:false
    t.timestamps
  end

... meanwhile.. back in the model layer

`class Project < ActiveRecord::Model
   has_many :pictures, :dependent => destroy
end`

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Model
  belongs_to :project
  validates_presence_of :project
end

To get all Judy's pictures

Client.where("name like ?", "Judy").projects.first.pictures

Answer (score 0):

I would have set it up like this

user has_many project_pictures

project_pictures belongs_to user

your project picture table should have a row for the user_id.